# Rails ActiveRecord query to select object by the number of related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models:

```
# game.rb

has_many :players, class_name: 'User'
```

and

```
# user.rb`

belongs_to :game
```

I want to do `Game.includes(:players).select { |game| game.players.count == 1 }`
with AR query, could you please advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rails 3 getting the count of the records that have more than one associate records (has_many)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199845/rails-3-getting-the-count-of-the-records-that-have-more-than-one-associate-recor) should help you out. The solution they give is:

```
Account.joins(:users).select('accounts.id').group('accounts.id').having('count(users.id) > 1')
```

In your case, try:

```
Game.joins(:players).select('games.id').group('games.id').having('count(users.id) = 1')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, error: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "players"`

Comment: I've edited the answer - didn't realise the class was User